VsCode LaTeX Workshop not showing any errors in the problems pane
Basically the title. If I put in an unknown environment for example, my file does not compile, but the problem pane is not showing any error and it's really tedious to find the line where I made a typo...
Also the problem remains the same for any recipe (latexmk, lualatex, ...)
I hope somebody can help me, I already tried every "fix" that I could find ...
Here are my settings:
{
    "latex-workshop.latex.build.forceRecipeUsage": false,
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [

        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "tools": [
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "latexmk (latexmkrc)",
            "tools": [
                "latexmk_rconly"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "latexmk (lualatex)",
            "tools": [
                "lualatexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "latexmk (xelatex)",
            "tools": [
                "xelatexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex * 2",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "bibtex",
                "pdflatex",
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Compile Rnw files",
            "tools": [
                "rnw2tex",
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Compile Jnw files",
            "tools": [
                "jnw2tex",
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Compile Pnw files",
            "tools": [
                "pnw2tex",
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "tectonic",
            "tools": [
                "tectonic"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [

        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "--max-print-line=10000",
                "-pdf",
                "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "lualatexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "-lualatex",
                "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "xelatexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "-xelatex",
                "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "latexmk_rconly",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "command": "pdflatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "bibtex",
            "command": "bibtex",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "rnw2tex",
            "command": "Rscript",
            "args": [
                "-e",
                "knitr::opts_knit$set(concordance = TRUE); knitr::knit('%DOCFILE_EXT%')"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "jnw2tex",
            "command": "julia",
            "args": [
                "-e",
                "using Weave; weave(\"%DOC_EXT%\", doctype=\"tex\")"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "jnw2texminted",
            "command": "julia",
            "args": [
                "-e",
                "using Weave; weave(\"%DOC_EXT%\", doctype=\"texminted\")"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "pnw2tex",
            "command": "pweave",
            "args": [
                "-f",
                "tex",
                "%DOC_EXT%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "pnw2texminted",
            "command": "pweave",
            "args": [
                "-f",
                "texminted",
                "%DOC_EXT%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "tectonic",
            "command": "tectonic",
            "args": [
                "--synctex",
                "--keep-logs",
                "%DOC%.tex"
            ],
            "env": {}
        }
    ],
    "ltex.language": "fr",
    "latex-workshop.message.badbox.show": "none",
    "latex-workshop.message.information.show": true,
   
}

